# pandas check if there are duplicates of repeated values between the two columns and not inside one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns and I want to check if there are duplicates of repeated values between the two columns and not inside one column. The length of the datasets is not equal. I am using

```py
df2['columnA'] = df1['columnA'].isin(df2['columnA'])
```

but it gives me the wrong answer.

I want to check if there are repeated values from the longer dataset in the shorter dataset. if yes I want a column to be added to the shorter dataset, indicating True. If not False

Dataset1:

```py
columnA

1598618777
553834731
1562313985
1138106620
1463509237
1560632350
```

Dataset2

```py
ColumnA

1330011201
1464235676
1232080731
1446254576
1563383895
1402595440
1555409735
1551787372
1523820531
1138106620
1196764367
1551787372
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create one dataframe with `append` and then use duplicated to check the duplicate and if you want to remove then you can use `.drop_duplicates`

```
df=Dataset1.append(Dataset1)
df.duplicated(subset=['ColumnA'])
```

Comment: I want to check if there are repeated values from the longer dataset in the shorter dataset. if yes I want a column to be added to the shorter dataset, named True. If not False

Comment: dataFrame['result']=False
dataFrame.loc[dataFrame['Name'].isin(dataFrame2['Name']),'result']=True